# trouble with char in java

Tags: java, while-loop

I am practicing and I want to create a code with a infinite loop the while loop, but my problem is that I don't know how to compare char or read char from the keyboard. So, far I have done the code below, any suggestions please ?

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Guess my favorite character: ");
        String letter = keyboard.nextLine();
        char secret = 'a';
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(" Enter guess:");
            String guess = keyboard.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++) {

                if (guess.chartAt(i).equals('a')) {
                    break;

                }

            }
           System.out.println("YOU got it!"); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error here: `guess.chartAt(i).equals('a')`? Have you looked up that error?

Comment: how would i do that ?

Comment: an yes i do have an error there so can i fix that ? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this;

```
String secret = "a";
Boolean isFounded = false;
while (true) {
    System.out.println(" Enter guess:");
    String guess = keyboard.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++) {
         if (guess.equals(secret)) {
              System.out.println("YOU got it!"); 
              isFounded = true;
         }
         if(isFounded) break;
     }
     if(isFounded) break;
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me what is the is(isFounded) statement ? is it the same as saying (isFound=true)? @Semih Eker

Comment: you must break not only for loop, you must break also while loop. Because of this, in if statement if the value founded, I make isFounded = true; and then use isfounded variable to break both for loop and while loop. Did you tried this code?

Comment: I am glad to help you, and as you mentioned, yes  if(isFounded) is equals to  if(isFounded == true). But isFounded is a Boolean varıable, so you can use shortly as i write in answer.

Answer (score 1):

`break` only jumps out of the `for` loop, so you have a infinite `while true` loop. You may want to try this way.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess my favorite character: ");
    String letter = keyboard.nextLine();
    char secret = 'a';
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(" Enter guess:");
        String guess = keyboard.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++) {
            if (guess.chartAt(i).equals('a')) {
                System.out.println("YOU got it!"); 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: guess.chartAt(i) == secret, chartAt is a typo in your program

Answer (score 0):

Only one loop here give it a try.

```
  String secret = "a";
  String guess = "";
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  while(!guess.contains(secret)){
     System.out.println(" Enter guess:");
     guess = keyboard.nextLine();
  }
  System.out.println("YOU got it!");
```